# Laravel image upload returning the PHP path?

Tags: php, laravel-5, image-uploading

Uploading images to S3 with laravel and having issues with this site when its worked fine before.

When returning the image from the form I get:

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php4SKXfX
```

My form is:

```
{!! Form::model($user, [
    'url' => ['user', $user->username],
    'class' => '',
    'files' => true,
    'method' => 'patch'
]) !!}
    {!! Form::file('profile_image', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
    {!! Form::button("Update Profile Image", ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success'])!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The error I was getting from my class was:

```
file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given
```

I have used this class before, but not working with this form I am making.

The way I am getting the image is:

```
return $request->file('profile_image');
```

Where am I going wrong?

This is the upload line for S3:

```
$image = $request->file('profile_image');

$uploaded = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/' . $fileName, file_get_contents($image));
```

Comment: Can you share all of the code where the error occurs, i.e. where you call `file_get_contents()`, I assume it's in your controller or upload logic.

Comment: @haakym updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given
```

Is telling you expects a path, not an object. You are passing it the result of `$request->file('profile_image')` which is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`.

You want to instead pass the file's path right? So I think you want to do this:

```
$image = $request->file('profile_image');

$uploaded = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/' . $fileName, file_get_contents($image->getClientOriginalName()));
```

See more details on dealing with file here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files

and docs for `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`

http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalName

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files):

> The object returned by the file method is an instance of the
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile class, which
>   extends the PHP SplFileInfo class and provides a variety of methods
>   for interacting with the file

Change code to something like:

`$uploaded = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/' . $fileName, file_get_contents($image->getPath() . '/' . $image->getFilename()));`